# App tracking transparency iOS 14.5 with newrelic

Tags: ios, swift, newrelic

From iOS 14.5 it is mandatory to use ATT framework if we are sharing user info to the third party or using advertising in the app. Does it require to use of ATT if we are only using newrelic framework in our code.

Comment: Have you discovered the response to this question?

Answer (score 0):

As the following [link](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-privacy-details/#optional-disclosure) points, "if the data is not linked with Third-Party Data for **advertising** or **advertising** measurement purposes", you don't need to implement AAT.
Our app was observed by Apple because we were tracking to third-party advertising libraries without implementing AAT. After removing this tracking (we didn't need it anymore) we were able to publish new versions of the app. We don't have issues for tracking to New Relic.